# How to handle page not found error in OWIN Katana?

Tags: .net, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

Let's say I have hotfound.html page and I want to show it when a page (or wab api method) was not found.

How can I handle it in OWIN application?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can make a OwinMiddleware to redirect NotFound responses (or any other responses).

```
class NotFoundMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public NotFoundMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("notfound.html");
        }
    }
}
```

or return the html directly in the response body (ie. no redirect).

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body))
            {
                string notFound = File.ReadAllText(@"Web\notfound.html");
                writer.Write(notFound);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that you may have to edit the response additionally depending on your specific case, but this works on my simple Owin server.

And in Startup.cs, add

```
 app.Use<NotFoundMiddleware>(app);
```

Comment: Oh great, thanks, this works. Is there a way to show the not found page without redirect? i.e. not to change the url in the browser?

Comment: You'd probably want to intercept the 404 status in the same way, but instead of redirecting you'll modify the response body to include some basic html (the not found page). If you look at the response from www.google.com/foo this is how they display their 404 page.

Comment: Ok, know I can modify the response body to return text response, but is there no way to return html file at this point?

Comment: I find that this does not work, because if there is no controller then calling `await Next.Invoke(context)` will result in the error being passed back to the user before I can call a redirect.